# Why are the graphs of $y=\frac12\sin(2\sin^{-1}(x+1))$ and $2\sin^{-1}(x+1)=\sin^{-1}(2y)$ not the same?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Is there a valid reason why they are not the same?
Because if you rearrange one equation then you get the other equation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a valid reason they should be?

Comment: Why should they be the same?

Comment: I imagine OP's reasoning is: if you rearrange one equation then you get the other equation....

Comment: if sin(x)=y from the x=sin^{-1}(y)  ?

Comment: Yes i'm talking about it @AdamRubinson

Comment: Please keep images in-post, and please don't undo edits from other users like this

Comment: @FShrike I tried but it didn't work. it seems now

Comment: They look like the same to me in the area where both of them are defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce this to its simplest form, draw the graphs of $y=\sin x$ and $x=\sin^{-1}y$ for a suitably large range of $x$ (say, $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$). You will see that the second graph is just a partial copy of the first graph.

Comment: Yes, it's a good example. thanks @TonyK

Answer (score 2):

It is true that for all real $\ x,\quad \sin(\arcsin x) = x. $

However, $\ \arcsin(\sin x) = x\quad $ is only true for $\ x\in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right].\ $

So whenever you have an equation and you take $\ \arcsin\ $ of both sides, you sometimes have to restrict the values of $x$ and $y$ (compared to before you took $\ \arcsin\ $ of both sides) so that the equation remains valid.

However, if you take $\ \sin\ $ of both sides of an equation, you do not have to restrict the values of $x$ and $y$ (compared to before you took $\ \sin\ $ of both sides).

Comment: Why would you restrict? e.g in the below graph point (-2,0) provides of the curve?

Comment: No, $\ 2\arcsin(-2+1) = -\pi \neq 0 = \arcsin(2\cdot 0).$

Comment: Yes you are right thank you @AdamRubinson :)

Comment: No problem. Yeah these arcsin and sin things are tricky, so you have to be careful when dealing with the domain and ranges....